# Target this anchor link via JS entered into href

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, href

Is it possible to target anchor link via JS entered into href?  I need to kill the cursor style on a SPECIFIC link.  I cannot do it any other way - so no css, jQuery, etc.  It has to go into a CMS via an insert js link on a link.

Example of input: `javascript:void(0);targetThisLink.style.cursor='default'`
Example of output inserted into the page/DOM: `<a href="javascript:void(0);targetThisLink.style.cursor='default'">Link</a>`

I tried `this.style.cursor='default'`.  It failed.  I am not sure this is possible, but if it is let me know.

Comment: On the same page or on some other page?

Comment: @mplungjan - same page.  I need to only target the very link that the code gets inserted in on.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on where your input comes from and how it's being translated to the output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="javascript:void(document.querySelector('a').style.cursor='default')">Link</a>
```

Note two things:

1. Style is only applied after user clicks on the link
2. You have to have a way to target that specific link via `querySelector`. Class or ID would be ideal. I used `a` tag but that would apply same style to all other links on the page. If nothing else possible try using `a[href^=javascript:]`

Comment: Yeah... good point with the click.  This isn't possible, but it does work after click - javascript:void(document.querySelector('a[href^=\'javascript:\']').style.cursor='default');

Comment: Unless there is some way to auto invoke it inside of the a tag hum...

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use mouseover in your CMS?

See example below:

```html
<a href="#" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='default'">Click Me</a>
```